# initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused in docker image

Tags: docker, centos, centos6

I am getting

```
$ sudo initctl list
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

On a docker image that has

```
$ uname -a
Linux 7276b783e0bf 4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
```

Any ideas what is going on? I thought CentOS6 is using Upstart by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just broadly assume that commands like `initctl` (and `systemctl` and `service`) don't work in Docker.  If you're trying to interactively start some new service in a running Docker container, that's not generally a best practice: you need to write a Dockerfile that causes the service to start on its own when the container starts up, usually by just running the server as a foreground process.

A Docker container runs *one* process (and its children).  Usually that's not an init-type process.  If you `docker run --rm -it centos:6` and get a GNU bash shell, that shell is the *only* process that's running in the container.  Upstart, systemd, and the assorted other system daemons they start won't be there.  (Try `ps -e` in your shell to see.)

If your actual question is "what Upstart-managed services are running in my CentOS 6 container", the answer is "none".